# Provide an object to a service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-providers

I'm trying to use a service implement by another person ([github](https://github.com/vankeer/ng2-neo4j)).

This service requires that a configuration be passed to it. According to the repo:

```
You have to configure Neo4jSettings in your bootstrap:

provide('Neo4jSettings', {useValue: {
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:7474',
    username: 'neo4j',
    password: 'neo4j42'
}})
```

Quite frankly I don't know what to do with this information as I've never had to inject settings into a service in the few tutorials I've followed. Google didn't help me much.

What I done so far is added the service to my module `home.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [Neo4jService] // Here it is
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

And my component, `home.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'vs-home',
  providers: [Neo4jService], // here
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private Neo4jService: Neo4jService) {} // and here
}
```

Predictably, when I run my app I get this error:

```
No provider for Neo4jSettings!
```

**My question is, how do I provide an object to a service? In this case, the `Neo4jSettings`.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Neo4jSettings` to your module providers, so it should look like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [
      Neo4jService,
      {
        provide: 'Neo4jSettings', useValue: {
            endpoint: 'http://localhost:7474',
            username: 'neo4j',
            password: 'neo4j42'
        }
    }
  ]
})

export class HomeModule {}
```